# How to set color of text in Input Box javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a Input box where I need to set the color of text which is being entered on the fly. I was not able to set the color using the `content.style.color` property. Here is the fiddle [for highlighting word in input box](https://jsfiddle.net/sekv9k4c/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `content.style.color = 'red';`

to `text.style.color = 'red';`

You want to set the style on the element, not the element's value.

Answer (score 0):

## Hello!

**content** was not defined.

**this should work for you**

```js
  var text = document.getElementById('text');
        text.addEventListener("keyup", function(event){
          func(event)});
          console.log(text);

        var colors = ["red","green","blue","pink","maroon"];

        var i = 0;

        function func(e){
          if(!(e.keyCode==32)){
            var content = text.value;
            document.getElementById('text').style.color = 'red';
          }

        }
```

```html
<div class="highlight">
      <input type="text" name="" value="" id="text">
    </div>
```

---

Hope I helped you!

Comment: Well, you coded it that way, you wrote that if keyCode != 32 the text color should change. I thought that you intended it

Comment: You mean OP coded it that way. I was stupid and didn't read the rest of the code. At least I'll admit it.

Comment: Oh yea, sorry, It's late haha ^^